# fscanf problems, taking a char a time

Tags: c, scanf

When I try to use fscanf to read a text file that contains
`PIZZA CHIPS BURGERS` as one of the lines. I am trying to add them to a variable, but instead it only takes one letter at a time.

```
if (infile) {
    while (fscanf(infile, "%c", &cit) > 0) {
        printf("%c\n",cit);
```

How do I make it take the word PIZZA instead of P I Z Z A?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but don't use `%c` then.  Use `"%s "` for a single string.

Comment: You should read more about `scanf` and its formatting codes. In `"%c"` the `c` means "character", i.e. it reads one character at a time. If you want to read a whole line you should use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: You are permitted to use `%255c`, for example, and it will read 255 characters (without skipping leading white space) plus a terminal null, regardless of spaces, newlines, etc.  Granted, the default for `%c` is equivalent to `%1c`, whereas the default for `%s` is an indefinite number of characters (and it skips leading white space, and stops at the first white space after the leading white space).  So, yes, you normally use the `%c` format like so and it reads a single character, but it isn't the only way to use it.

Comment: @dLiGHT: Use `fgets` to read a line.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Well for my assignment, I have `BUFFALO NEW YORK 12345` I am working with city, state, and population. How do I extract each column into each separate array?

Comment: That's messy; how do you know where the boundary between city (many cities have two words in their name) and the state (some states have two words, some have just one) is?  Also, what happened to the rest of the population of NY state?

Comment: @dLiGHT: How are you supposed to know that `BUFFALO NEW YORK` is a 1-word city and a 2-word state, and `LOS ANGELES CALIFORNIA` is a 2-word city and a 1-word state? The only way I can think of to do that is to check against a list of state names. (I wonder if there's a town in Virginia called "West".)

Comment: That's the problem ;[ I made up the population as an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
char word[256];

if (infile)
{
    while (fscanf(infile, "%255s", word) == 1)
        printf("Word: %s\n", word);
}
```

Note that if you want a whole line read in at a time, spaces and all, then you'll use `fgets()`:

```
char line[4096];

if (infile)
{
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), infile) != 0)
        printf("Line: %s", line);
}
```

NB: `fgets()` keeps the newline unless the line is so long that it has to be truncated, so the `printf()` format doesn't need a newline of its own.  Generally, it is easier to control input if you use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` than if you use just `scanf()` or `fscanf()`.  In particular, you can usually give better error diagnostics because you have all of what the user typed.  You can also try alternative formats if that's necessary.